# Trouble with removing event listeners in react app

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, dom-events

Here is my code in a react app:

```
useEffect(() => {
    handleCheckboxActivation();
}, [xboxActivated]);

function handleCheckboxActivation() {
  if (xboxActivated) {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".MuiCheckbox-root");
    checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
      checkbox.addEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseoverCheckbox);
    });
  } else {
      const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll(".MuiCheckbox-root");
      checkboxes.forEach((checkbox) => {
        checkbox.removeEventListener("mouseover", handleMouseoverCheckbox);
      });
  }
}
```

`xboxActivated` is in state and if it's `true` then I want to add event listeners to all of the `Material-ui` checkboxes.  If it's `false` I want to remove all of the event listeners.  Adding them is working but they don't seem to be able to be removed.  I've tried assigning `handleMouseoverCheckbox` to a variable, as well as adding `true` in the event listener function call to make the event listeners more distinguishable. So my first question is how to get the removeEventListener to actually remove them (I've searched online considerably) and then also more generally is there a react specific approach to dealing with event listeners on groups of elements or is using vanilla javascript the only way to approach this problem.  I haven't found a good example of using `useRef` that fits this problem statement.

Solution:
For future reference the solution was in fact to wrap `handleMouseOverCheckbox` with `useCallback` and here is what that function looks like ->

```
const handleMouseoverCheckbox = useCallback((event) => {
    ...do stuff
}, []);
```

Comment: Probably you handling function handleMouseoverCheckbox is changing between renders. So on next component render it point to different (new version) of it. Because removeEventListener have to get the same value (pointer) to function to remove it, is  not working. Define handleMouseoverCheckbox with useCallback and it should start working.

Comment: How are you setting the xboxActivated?